# What determines element/bucket size? - Hash Index

Tags: indexing, hash, associative-array

Promise i've searched and people have asked similar questions but the answer always seems to be it's not technically possible but without saying why. I've done a Google search also and get the same info.

I'm asking this from a language independent front. I know that a hash index works by creating an array and then putting a key through a hash function which then maps to an index in the array. The literature always says that you can only have one value per key which i presume depending on data type/cpu means 4,8 bytes per element/index in memory. I know that you can have multiple values per key if you use a pointer to another array or list but what technically stops you declaring for example key = car value = Audi, Blue, estate, 19 inch wheels and placing more bytes in that one element?

Is it because a call to an index needs to be in one memory read and the max size a bucket can be is the same as the data bus width? Or is it because that's the way the compiler is designed and in theory they could of made the compiler work with code that stated it wanted more than one value per key? Or finally is it perhaps related to the hash function only working because it knows the size of the array beforehand and that to fit all key/value pairs in contiguous memory it needs each element to only store one value?

Apologies if i'm missing something really obvious but i just can't see why it's not technically possible. Thanks for listening to me go on lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, Rob!

**Nothing can have multiple values**. For example, you can't have multiple values for a variable in mathematics. X can't be both 1 and 0, unless we are talking [quantum computing](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-a-quantum-computer-explained-with-a-simple-example-b8f602035365/). Similarly, you can't have multiple values per key.

Another way to look at it is using [functional dependency](https://opentextbc.ca/dbdesign01/chapter/chapter-11-functional-dependencies/), which states that if the key X has the values Y and Z, then you can have the key X twice, once pointing to Y, and once pointing to Z. This means you will need duplicate keys, which we can't do in hash maps.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i still don't get what you mean as the hash maps to an index in the array and not a particular value. The value can be anything you like right? So what determines the element/bucket size in bytes?

Comment: Sorry, I suppose I did not understand your question. Please revise it because "Why is it not possible to have multiple values per key?" is not the same as "what determines the element/bucket size in bytes" in a hash map.

Comment: Just updated :) But still confused lol. If you can change the bucket size, why can't we say key maps to index 0 + offset 20 bytes and then declare a few values in that bucket?

Comment: You can do that using array lists. You say you "know that you can have multiple values per key if you use a pointer to another array or list." That's your answer. Having multiple values (ungrouped in an array) per key would violate key uniqueness, according to functional dependency, as I mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks for that and i get pointing to another array or list. Can i ask then what determines the bucket size of the array in bytes. Lets say the hash function for 5 values maps to 0-4 buckets. Can't we say after the function has run, increment the base address of the first bucket to x number of bytes and so on for the rest of the key to bucket hashes. Then we would be able to fit more values per key. Basically why can't we fit a table row's worth of info into a hash table?

Comment: Well, you can, actually. You can just append more items to the list that the key maps to. That's just an abstraction for increasing the bucket size. There is no restriction. There are different abstractions in each language but there is always a way to fit more values per key. If you have a language specific question about that, we can answer it in a different thread.

Comment: Thanks oamandawi! I'm hoping that what you've just described is what i'm thinking in my head lol. So are you saying that a 'List' is actually making that particular index/bucket larger? And not that its a completely different array in a different location in Ram? If it is the former, wouldn't that eat into the space of the adjacent index's space though?

Comment: No, it's an abstraction. Design wise, I think most languages use a pointer to a linked list in some other address space. This video explains the advantages and disadvantages of the different designs well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UycDHbcWco0

Comment: So i think i understand now and again thanks for your help :) Are you trying to say that when you hash a key, it can only have one value because it hashes to only one index in the array which can only hold one value?

Comment: Perfect! You got it!